# During install or build: How to go around ".... requires Python '>=3.a.b' but the running Python is 3.x.y"

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've cloned a project from github which specifically requires python 3.6.0 to run properly. It requires tensorflow `2.3.1` which requires `protobuf`
on installing tensorflow i get `protobuf requires Python '>=3.7' but the running Python is 3.6.0`

Can anyone help please how to get protobuf work in py 3.6.0

Comment: You probably need to make sure you install an older version of `protobuf`. If you have the proper older version of `tensorflow`, it's own requirements may only specify that it needs `protobuf`, so `pip`(?) is just installing the newest version it can find, not the "newest" version that was available when the old `tensorflow` was released.

Comment: What's stopping you from upgrading Python? I highly doubt your project requires exactly Python 3.6.0

Comment: I've installed successfully protobuf 3.9 (an older version) which is the version required by tensorflow 2.3.1 , but still when i run pip install tensorflow==2.3.1 i still get the same error

Comment: You need pyenv - see answer.  I often wonder why pyenv is not installed by default for every user on any Linux like install where Python system level scripts are critial to the correct running.  e.g. It's very easy to screw up Ubuntu by installing some system wide packages or trying to force update or otherwise replace the system level Python interpreter.  There should certainly be a system level PyEnv.

Comment: i've tried the project on Python 3.9 it misbehaved

Comment: I think it could be much easier if there is a way to specify the version of protobuf i want to be installed in tensorflow.

Answer (score 1):

**Warning** the following answer involves intalling outdated packages which is a **bad** idea.

I came across a similar error when trying to install google-cloud-storage on raspbian:

```
$ python3 -m pip install google-cloud-storage --user
Collecting google-cloud-storage
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bf/02/0c48179c0917e72e7853dcb24382ecfd4a6eb814fe881713f809825d26eb/google_cloud_storage-1.32.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl

...

  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/19/c7/fa589626997dd07bd87d9269342ccb74b1720384a4d739a1872bd84fbe68/chardet-4.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting protobuf>=3.12.0 (from google-api-core<2.0.0dev,>=1.21.0->google-cloud-core<2.0dev,>=1.4.1->google-cloud-storage)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6c/be/4e32d02bf08b8f76bf6e59f2a531690c1e4264530404501f3489ca975d9a/protobuf-4.21.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
protobuf requires Python '>=3.7' but the running Python is 3.5.3
```

I could install a version of protobuf that played well with my python version by checking the available releases of protobuf [in pypi](https://pypi.org/project/protobuf/#history) and doing:

```
$ python3 -m pip install protobuf==3.19.4 --user
Collecting protobuf==3.19.4
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c6/1c/f18d97fc479b4fb6f72bbb0e41188575362e3bbd31014cf294ef0fdec8bf/protobuf-3.19.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (162kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 163kB 544kB/s 
Installing collected packages: protobuf
Successfully installed protobuf-3.19.4
```

I then had to find an [old version of google-cloud-storage](https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-storage/#history)  that worked with my old version of protobuf and install them together:

```
$ python3 -m pip install google-cloud-storage==1.24.1 protobuf==3.19.4 --user

...

Successfully installed cachetools-4.2.4 certifi-2022.5.18 chardet-4.0.0 google-api-core-1.23.0 google-auth-1.23.0 google-cloud-core-1.4.4 google-cloud-storage-1.24.1 google-resumable-media-0.5.1 googleapis-common-protos-1.52.0 idna-2.10 protobuf-3.19.4 pyasn1-0.4.8 pyasn1-modules-0.2.8 pytz-2022.2.1 requests-2.25.1 rsa-4.7.2 setuptools-50.3.2 six-1.16.0 urllib3-1.26.9
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are able to replace your system wide Python interpreter, (which is not often a good idea unless you really know what you are doing), you should be using something like pyenv.  There are other methods that work for some use cases such as Docker or a VM.

[pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) (or for [Windows](https://github.com/pyenv-win/pyenv-win#installation)) Creates a standalone copy of a full Python interpreter install by altering your runtime environment dynamically.  It gets round the issues with altering your system wide install.

You can have any number of Python interpreter versions available at the same time and simply switch between them on a project by project or even do repeated tests of different versions on the same project.

Is best installed using [pyenv-installer](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-installer), though there may be a packaged version for your platform.  (Though you don't mention what platform you are on).

Because pyenv only alters the current user environment it can often be installed with no system level privelages and without any side effects on system level commands.

PyEnv works well with [PipEnv](https://pypi.org/project/pipenv/), through which you can also avoid every projects having to share exactly the same python modules at the exactly the same versions.